# auto - как получить тип по значению, а не по ссылке или указателю?

Tags: c++, c++11

Допустим есть такой код:

```
std::vector<int> v({1,2,3,4});
auto x = v.front();
```

Как сделать, чтобы переменная x имела тип `int`, а не `int&` или `const int&`?
Как сделать ссылку или указатеть понятно - нужно добавить к auto & или *. А как сделать значение? (Хочется объявить x без указания типа, так как тип может быть слишком сложным и громоздким и к тому же тип элемента в векторе может поменяться.)

Comment: а разве она не int?

Comment: С чего вы решили, что `x` будет иметь тип `int&`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В приведённом случае тип `x` будет `int`. Т.е. описанной вами проблемы нет. А вот чтобы он стал ссылкой - нужно вместо `auto` писать `decltype(auto)`, но это уже c++14 и выше.

[Пример:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oSbrGA281f0UNq5Y)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 

    std::vector<int> v({1,2,3,4});
    decltype(auto) x = v.front();

    x = 42;

    for (auto e : v)
    {
        std::cout << e << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

> ```
> 42 2 3 4
> ```

Если оставить `auto` [вывод](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bTgnXPBifS48ERFb) будет без изменений:

> ```
> 1 2 3 4
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите удалить ссылочность от типа, то можете воспользоваться шаблоном. Например вот так:

```
auto x = static_cast<std::remove_reference<decltype(v.front())>::type>(v.front());
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>


std::vector<int> v({1,2,3,4});
std::remove_reference<decltype(v[0])>::type a = v[0];
```